# Django ERROR: Not environment configured

Tags: python, django, compiler-errors

When i try to runserver from terminal or by using Pycharm  i get An Error like :

```
"ERROR: Not environment configured"
```

I Have never met that error. I'm starting it for a first time on linux+pycharm,  but I had it done before on linux+aptana and  windows+pycharm. Project is using virtualenv, Pycharm sees all imports etc.. lampp server  is also  running.  Unfortunately i haven't found any clues on google/stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `django-project-template`?

It has that line [here](https://github.com/gibas/django-project-template/blob/master/project_name/settings.py#L161) and it happens when it can't find settings for the current hostname (the output of `socket.gethostname().lower()`).

To fix it you need to check the hostname of the server you're running on and specify Django project settings for it.